# Estimating latent distribution based on order statistic

Tags: self-study, estimation, order-statistics

I understand that generally the latent distribution $F$ and the distribution of the first and second order statistic of 2 independent draws from $F$ are related as follows:

$$ F_{(1)}(x) = 1- (1-F(x))^2 = 2F(x) - F(x)^2$$
$$ F_{(2)}(x) = F(x)^2 $$

which I can rewrite to identify $F$ from the respective order statistics:
$$ F(x) = 1 - \sqrt{1- F_{(1)}(x)}$$
$$ F(x) = \sqrt{F_{(2)}(x)}$$

Now suppose I make the following three observations:

1.: $x_1 = 1/2$, $x_2 = 1$

2.: $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 3$

3.: $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 7$

Therefore, the empirical CDFs are as follows: $\hat F_{(1)}(1/2) = 1/3$, $\hat F_{(1)}(1) = 2/3$, $\hat F_{(1)}(2) = 1$ and $\hat F_{(2)}(1) = 1/3$, $\hat F_{(2)}(3) = 2/3$, $\hat F_{(2)}(7) = 1$.

I understand that I can obtain estimates of the empirical $\hat F(x)$ by using above expressions, i.e., $1 - \sqrt{1- \hat F_{(1)}(x)}$ and $ \sqrt{\hat F_{(2)}(x)}$, respectively.

So if estimate $\hat F$ based on the first order statistic, I obtain that $\hat F(2) = 1$. However, if I estimate $F$ based on the second order statistic, I obtain that $\hat F(3) \approx 0.81$, which implies that $\hat F(2) < 0.81$.

Therefore, the estimate based on the second order statistic is immediately rejected by the estimate based on the first order statistic. Even though both of them are supposed to be consistent, which of them can I more 'rely' on?

Comment: (1) Consider using the *joint* distribution of the order statistics to obtain better information from the data.  (2) Please explain what procedure you are using to "estimate $F$ based on" an order statistic.

Comment: Alright, added the estimation procedure in the question text.

Comment: @whuber (1) "better" in which sense?

Comment: I still don't follow, because your expressions are ambiguous: it's important to distinguish the actual $F$ from the empirical $F$ and to explain what you mean by the empirical $F$ for these data--especially because you don't have full observations of each dataset.  "Better" means tending to be more accurate.

Comment: @whuber clarified it in the question text. Sorry for the ambiguity.